# How to disable http port in play framework?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

When I run Play Framework using https port, application starts on two ports - default (9000) and https (443).
How to disabled default 9000 port and run the Play application ONLY on https port?

I run application through the following command:

```
play -Dhttps.port=443 -Dhttps.keyStore=/path/to/keystore -Dhttps.keyStorePassword=password start
```

I get some logs:

> [info] play - Application started (Prod)
>   [info] play - Listening for
>   HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
>   [info] play - Listening for HTTPS on
>   port /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:443

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using the **http.port=disabled** flag

```
play -Dhttp.port=disabled -Dhttps.port=443 -Dhttps.keyStore=/path/to/keystore -Dhttps.keyStorePassword=password start
```

Comment: and what about in `production mode`? what should be the attribute in conf file?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this can't be done in the same way in the Gradle Play Plugin, See: https://github.com/gradle/playframework/issues/85