# how to use https instead of http in playframework

Tags: playframework

I would like to use only https port in my play application. I've successfully added -Dhttps.port=9043 in command line parameters and play started using two ports default http=9000 and https=9043. How to configure play to stop using http port?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable http port in play framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24864163/how-to-disable-http-port-in-play-framework)

Comment: Tag your question properly

Answer (score 0):

In Play 2.x, set `http.port` to `disabled` instead of providing a port number:

```
./start -Dhttp.port=disabled -Dhttps.port=9043 # (...)
```

[Configuring HTTPS - Turning HTTP off](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ConfiguringHttps)